# Does Programmers accept "Will apple accept or reject my app?" questions? Why or why not?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

More generally, does Programmers accept questions of a customer service nature having to do with Apple's app submission process?

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922619/102937

Do you think Apple will reject my application if it is using this code ?

```
+ (BOOL)isJailbroken 
{
    BOOL jailbroken = NO;
    NSString *cydiaPath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";
    NSString *aptPath = @"/private/var/lib/apt/";

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cydiaPath]) {
        jailbroken = YES;
    }

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:aptPath]) {
        jailbroken = YES;
    }

    return jailbroken;
}
```

Comment: did you forget the "we are not customer service/support" or whatever that section of what stack overflow is not was called?

Comment: @Ryathal: "What Stack Overflow is Not" [was deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted).

Comment: its deletion does not invalidate its points.

Comment: @Ryathal: Yes, it does.  You have to debate the point all over again.

Comment: answering homework questions, being Google, being X product customer support didn't magically become acceptable for a brief period while they were re-debated, a crude but useful explanation of why they are all unacceptable was deleted not the rules themselves.

Comment: @Ryathal: Well, I got it on the record here.

Answer (score 8):

No we shouldn't accept questions like this.

Why not?

In the general case we don't know what Apple's (or Microsoft's for that matter) acceptance criteria are. We would only be guessing.

In the specific case we could make a good guess that they would reject it - but it would still be a guess.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree for Stack Overflow as well.  People complain vociferously when I close these questions there, but why should we do Apple's customer service for them (badly)?

Comment: Good answer, I'll add that the question is likely to be too localised: no-one else is going to be submitting the same app, the review rules change over time.